# How to put this result inside that result?

Tags: comment-meta, wp-comment-query

I want my comment results to put inside anoher result.

I want this result

```
        $args = array(
                    'post_id'   =>$post->ID,
                    'status'  => 'approve',
                    'type'  => 'review_comment',
                );
                $comments = get_comments( $args );
                $abb = $comment->comment_content;
                $acc = get_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID, COMMENT_TITLE_METAKEY, true);
                $add = get_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID, COMMENT_RATING_METAKEY, true);
                $aee = get_comment_date( 'd\/m\/Y' );
                $aff = get_the_title();
                $agg = $comment->comment_author;
       $comlist = "review" => [
            "@type" => "Review",
            "headline" => $acc,
            "reviewbody" => $abb,
            "datePublished" => $aee,
            "itemReviewed" => [
                "@type" => "Organization",
                "name" => $aff,
                ],
            "author " => [
                "@type" => "Person",
                "name" => $agg,
                ],  
        ];

                $comlistall = foreach ( $comments as $comment ){

                     $comlist ;

                };
```

to put inside this result.

```
    <?php
    $rtitlez = get_the_title();
    $rimgz = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full');
    $rvaluez = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'comments_rating_value', true);
    $rcountz = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'comments_rating_count', true);
 $result = [
  "@context" => "https://schema.org/",
  "@type" => "Organization",
  "name" => $rtitlez,
  "image" => $rimgz,
  "aggregateRating" => [
        "@type" => "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue" => $rvaluez,
        "bestRating" => "5",
        "worstRating" => "1",
        "ratingCount" => $rcountz
      ],
    /*I want here $comlistall*/

  ]
  ;?>                       
<script type="application/ld+json"><?php echo json_encode($result); ?></script>
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Run the loop in advance and populate an array, which in turn you include in the `$result` afterward.

```
<?php
 // Create an empty array
 $comlistall = array();

 foreach ( $comments as $comment ){
   $comlistall[] = $comment; // <= Populate the array with the comments in the loop
 };

 $rtitlez = get_the_title();
 $rimgz = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full');
 $rvaluez = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'comments_rating_value', true);
 $rcountz = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'comments_rating_count', true);

 $result = [
  "@context" => "https://schema.org/",
  "@type" => "Organization",
  "name" => $rtitlez,
  "image" => $rimgz,
  "aggregateRating" => [
        "@type" => "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue" => $rvaluez,
        "bestRating" => "5",
        "worstRating" => "1",
        "ratingCount" => $rcountz
      ],
   "comlistall" => $comlistall, // insert the comment array in your $results array
  ];
?>
<script type="application/ld+json"><?php echo json_encode($result); ?></script>
```

**Update**

If you only want certain attributes from the comments, simply create your own array with the attributes you want. In this example `$comment` is an array with the attributes. Modify to your needs.

```
// ...
foreach ( $comments as $comment ){
  $c = [
    "@type" => "Review",
    "headline" => $comment["headline"],
    "reviewbody" => $comment["reviewbody"],
    "datePublished" => $comment["datePublished"],
    "itemReviewed" => [
       "@type" => "Organization",
       "name" => $comment["name"],
    ],
    "author " => [
       "@type" => "Person",
       "name" => $comment["authorname"],
    ],  
  ];

  $comlistall[] = $c;
};
// ...
```

Comment: Your answer works. But now I'm having a problem with the output. comment or get_comments return everything on the comment. I need the desired output like the one I made in $comlist.

Comment: @Bikram I have updated the answer.

Comment: Hi, everything works now. But still, there is something extra added I think. I couldn't figure out the issue.

Have a look - https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=brightdelhi.in%2Freview%2Fzzzz