# Correct way to retrieve comment attributes for desired results

Tags: comments

I'm playing with this code but can't get it to work 100%. Comments return everything associated with it, but I want to retrieve the comments with only the desired attributes.

```
<?php

    $args = array(
                    'post_id'   =>$post->ID,
                    'status'  => 'approve',
                    'type'  => 'wp_review_comment',
                );
     $comments = get_comments( $args );

    // Create an empty array
    $comlistall = array();

    foreach ( $comments as $comment ){

          $c = [ "review" => [
            "@type" => "Review",
            "headline" => (get_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID, WP_REVIEW_COMMENT_TITLE_METAKEY, true)),
            "reviewbody" => ($comment->comment_content),
            "datePublished" => (get_comment_date( 'd\/m\/Y' )),
            "itemReviewed" => [
                "@type" => "Organization",
                "name" => (get_the_title()),
                ],
            "author " => [
                "@type" => "Person",
                "name" => ($comment->comment_author),
                ],
            "reviewRating"=> [
                "@type" => "Rating",
                "ratingValue" => (get_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID, WP_REVIEW_COMMENT_RATING_METAKEY, true)),
                ],
             "publisher" => [
                 "@type" => "Organization",
                 "name" => "Sitejury",
                 "sameAs" => "https://sitejury.com",
                ],
            ]
        ];  
        $comlistall[] = $c;
    };

$result = [
  "@context" => "https://schema.org/",
  "@type" => "Organization",
  "name" => (get_the_title()),
  "image" => (get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full')),
  "aggregateRating" => [
        "@type" => "AggregateRating",
        "bestRating" => "5",
        "worstRating" => "1",
        "ratingValue" => (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wp_review_comments_rating_value', true)),
        "ratingCount" => (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wp_review_comments_rating_count', true)),
  ],
    $comlistall,
] ;?>                       

<script type="application/ld+json"><?php echo json_encode($result); ?></script>
```

Currently, my problem is that now the results are rapped in a `"0" = [{` attribute. I'm trying to get rid of the `"0" = [{` attribute.

result url: https://sitejury.com/review/zzzzzz/

Checking structured data: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sitejury.com%2Freview%2Fzzzzzz%2F

Callback question: [How to put this result inside that result](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/357986/how-to-put-this-result-inside-that-result).

Result I want: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sitejabber.com%2Freviews%2Fbillmelater.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the `get_comment_date( 'd\/m\/Y' )` resulted in a PHP notice in my case, so I changed that to `get_comment_date( 'd\/m\/Y', $comment )` (i.e. I pass the `$comment` object to the function).

Now the issue with your code is that the `$result` should have a `review` item with the value being an array of reviews (review objects):

```php
$result = [
  "@context" => "https://schema.org/",
  "@type" => "Organization",
  "name" => (get_the_title()),
  "image" => (get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full')),
  "aggregateRating" => [
    ...
  ],
  'review' => $comlistall, // here, a "review" item must exists
/* Or something like so:
  'review' => array(
    array( "@type" => "Review", "headline" => ..., "reviewbody" => ..., ... ),
    array( "@type" => "Review", "headline" => ..., "reviewbody" => ..., ... ),
    ...
  ),
*/
];
```

Secondly, your `$comlistall` should produce an array which when it's represented in JSON format, looks like the <strike>first</strike> one [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/G1QAHUOp) (see the "Changed Text").

So to fix the issue:

1. As I mentioned above, in the `$result`, use `'review' => $comlistall`.
2. Change this:

   ```php
   $c = [ "review" => [
     "@type" => "Review",
     "headline" => (get_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID, WP_REVIEW_COMMENT_TITLE_METAKEY, true)),
     "reviewbody" => ($comment->comment_content),
     ...
   ] ];
   $comlistall[] = $c;
   ```

   to this (but you may assign the review data/object to the variable `$c`):

   ```php
   $comlistall[] = [
     "@type" => "Review",
     "headline" => (get_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID, WP_REVIEW_COMMENT_TITLE_METAKEY, true)),
     "reviewbody" => ($comment->comment_content),
     ...
   ];
   ```

Comment: Thanks man. It worked.

Comment: You're welcome! And I edited a substantial typo ("first one") in the answer..